# how to design navigation drawer & title bar?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-titlebar

i want to design a **navigation drawer** for my app . In it i want various options to go to various activity.
 I also want to add some **clickable items** on **title bar** which would go to any activity specified.

so, please suggest me direction to proceed.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far along the lines of https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Best example is add new activity and select "Navigation Drawer Activity"
That use titlebar item for opening menu and swip for opening and closing menu